# Silverstripe Handler

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to find ways to do a piece of functionality which is nice to have. Not sure how to approach. Proper silverstripe way would be good.

I have a website (built in Silverstripe)that has multiple types of products, example

- Payment type (Products that needs payment)
- Email type (Products that does not need payment but just requires users email)
- Just delivery type (Products that does not need payment but need users address)

The idea is, users can add anytype of product to the basket and basket summary shows all the different types of products the user has added to basket. Once the user clicks checkout button , each type of product has its own handler to do the checkout.

How can i achieve this? Ideas please i.e how should I structure/architect it.

Ideally I would like to have this URL structure

http://example.com/orders/checkout/Payment

http://example.com/orders/checkout/Email

http://example.com/orders/checkout/Delivery

R

Comment: Have you had a look at a module like [SwipeStripe](http://swipestripe.com/)?

Comment: This seems a good concept, in theory, but perhaps is adding a little overhead to the system. You are in essence going to be passing a user from one URL to the other to the other throughout checkout. Ideally, you want only one controller for your checkout process, that looks up all of its items, and based on if certain information is required, simply ask for it. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you start with an existing SilverStripe e-commerce module.

- https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-core
- http://www.silvercart.org/
- https://github.com/sunnysideup/silverstripe-ecommerce

SilverShop is my personal preference.